# Creating map with/without make

Tags: go

What exactly is the difference between

```
var m = map[string]int{}
```

and

```
var m = make(map[string]int)
```

Is the first just a shortcut for faster field initialization? Are there performance considerations?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The second form always creates an empty map.

The first form is a special case of a map literal. Map literals allow to create *non empty* maps:

```
m := map[bool]string{false: "FALSE", true: "TRUE"}
```

Now your (generalized) example:

```
m := map[T]U{}
```

is a map literal with no initial values (key/value pairs). It's completely equivalent to:

```
m := make(map[T]U)
```

Additionally, `make` is the only way to specify an initial capacity to your map which is larger than the number of elements initially assigned. Example:

```
m := make(map[T]U, 50)
```

will create a map with enough space allocated to hold 50 items. This can be useful to reduce future allocations, if you know the map will grow.

Comment: Alright. I thought maybe there is a difference in allocation.

Comment: The only difference is that `make` is the only way you can manually specify the capacity of the map. In general the language is supposed to handle the size of maps for you, but if you know the map is going to hold a maximum of N elements, you can minimize the runtime costs by allocating the map with `make(map[T]T, N)`. As a sidenote, the builtin `cap` function does not work on maps.

Comment: I know that. I was just curious if maybe one is allocated on the stack and the other on the heap.

Comment: @JimmyZelinskie in your description I'd change "maximum of N elements" to "at least N elements" or "around N elements". The size "hint" given to `make` for a map is the *initial allocation*; it can still grow beyond N with the same memory and performance as not specifying any size. The "hint" helps  avoid any resizing as elements 1 through N get added.