# Interface declaration difference

Tags: go

As a beginner gopher, i'm struggling to understand the difference between:

```
m := map[string]interface{}{}
```

and

```
m := make(map[string]interface{})
```

I tried to find an explanation, but couldn't find anything.

Comment: The two statements do the same thing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating map with/without make](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959992/creating-map-with-without-make)

Comment: But why 2 pairs of braces?

Comment: In the first form, you're creating a map literal. The type is `map[string]interface{}`, which must be followed by the key/value pairs enclosed in braces. In your case, you're initializing an empty map, so you have `{}`.

Comment: @AndySchweig thanks. Now I see that `m := map[string]interface{}{"key": "val"}` works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are the same except that when using `make`, you can (of course optionally) specify the size of the map you're trying to initialize.

For e.g.,

```
m := make(map[string]interface{}, 10)
```

Also, when you initialize a map literal like this -

```
m := map[string]interface{}{}
```

you can add values to it then and there. In this case you have initialized it to a `nil` map. If you'd rather create a map in which you want to be able to add things in future (i.e. `append`), you should use either the first method or initialize it as

```
var m map[string]interface{}
```