# save and loading custom types

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

I have a custom type `map[string]map[string]string` am trying to save in Google Datastore, the save works as expected. However the load functions complains about `assignment to entry in nil map`

```
//Address represents address
type Address map[string]map[string]string
```

Type above is a map of map[string]string, target at saving different address types.

```
//Load function from PropertyLoaderInterface helps datastore load this object
func (a *Address) Load(dp []datastore.Property) error {
    for _, property := range dp {
        (*a)[property.Name] = util.InterfaceToMapString(property.Value)
    }
    return nil
}
```

In the load function I deference the Address which is a map of map[string]string, it saves the following example JSON format.

```
"Company":{
    "physicalAddress": "",
    "postalAddress": "",
    "physicalCity": "",
    "postalCity": "",
    "physicalCode": "",
    "postalCode": "",
    "physicalCountry": "",
    "postalCountry": ""
}
```

Save function below works well and data is store in datastore. The Load is however rather a tricky bugger.

```
//Save function from PropertyLoaderInterface helps datastore save this object
func (a *Address) Save() ([]datastore.Property, error) {
    propertise := []datastore.Property{}
    for name, value := range *a {
        propertise = append(propertise, datastore.Property{Name: name,
            NoIndex: true,
            Value:   util.MapToJSONString(value)})
    }

    return propertise, nil
}
```

**Working load for Address struct**

```
func (a *Address) Load(dp []datastore.Property) error {
    *a = make(Address)

    for _, property := range dp {
        (*a)[property.Name] = util.InterfaceToMapString(property.Value)
    }
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, regarding the declarations - https://stackoverflow.com/a/42901715/4720042

Next, I feel you should instead use a custom struct for this purpose.
Even if you still want to use a `map[string]map[string]string`, you cannot assign to a field in a map that hasn't been explicitly defined viz. `property.Name`

You have to initialize that map with `make` if you plan on adding the elements later.

Comment: I tried initializing the structure in the load function thinking that would also initialize the map a = &Address{} however though error is not thrown the output is nil. I need addresses to be presented as map[string]map[string]string I don't see how else adjusting the Address structure would help. An address would be used for other models Company, User, Store etc. if I can save I should be able to load with very little effort in my view.

Comment: Before you call `Load` just initialize whatever variable you're passing to it, in this case `a` as a := make(Address) 
I've tried to replicate your issue here - https://play.golang.org/p/zaRBJVtmgy

Comment: I understand that case, however in the instance of datastore, I don't have the privilege to init before datastore calls load or save. All happens internally.

Comment: In that case, use *a = make(Address) in the first line of your function Load. Is that possible to do?

Comment: Work like a charm, I had declared as follows a = &Address{}, however *a = make(Address) is a winner. Thank you for your time.